# Bypassing the "confirmation" page before redirecting back to webshop

Tags: payment, gateway, confirmation

We have a customer here in Denmark, who also sells products abroad to the US.
Therefore they use Authorize.net as payment gateway.

The issue is, that when a payment has been approved, there's a "Confirmation" page in Authorize.net where the customer has to click "Continue" - even though the payment has been made.
If the customer does NOT click Continue on that page, he's not being redirected back to the webshop (DynamicWeb platform) and thus, doesn't see they webshop confirmation page, which results in the order not being properly "finnished", confirmationpage shown, confirmation email sent, and written to the ERP-system.

How can we bypass this "continue" page in authorize.net and send the customer directly to the webshops confirmation page.

Thank you in advance :)

I've been in contact with DynamicWeb who says that it's a "thing" to be fixed in Authorize.net
Authorize.Net support couldn't help and referred me here to the community.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.